# Trying to join two MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want these two different table results in a single query.

```
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE keyskill LIKE'php%'");
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE parentaddress LIKE'chennai%'");
```

Can any one please help me?

Here is the table structure...

Table 1:

```
  ID | F. Name | L.Name | Gender | Parentaddress  
___________________________________________________
 12  | Peter   | Son    |  Male  |  Chennai
 13  | Johny   | Depp   |  Male  |  Coimbatore
```

Table 2:

```
 S.No|    Name | Title   | Gender | Keyskill  
 ___________________________________________________
 13  | Johny   | Student |  Male  |  PHP
 12  | Peter   | Student |  Male  |  JAVA
```

Comment: These have different columns?

Comment: Please provide tables' structure

Comment: is that 2 tables have same field and name?

Comment: at least there should be one common column between them

Comment: Post the table structure and some sample data

Comment: If you don't have any foreign key, you can't merge these two in a single one. It is a database model matter, not a php one.

Comment: id and s.no are the foreign keys

Comment: If i choose chennai the rows which having parent address as chennai should be displayed and if I choose php the rows which having the keyskill PHP should be displayed... I have called the keyskill and address by PHP variable..

Comment: ("SELECT * FROM student_4 WHERE keyskill='php'" OR "SELECT * FROM student_1 WHERE parentaddress='chennai'")

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your database look like this? (Just guessing!)

Table 1 (People):

```
  ID | F. Name | L.Name | Gender | Parentaddress  | Title  
__________________________________________________________
 12  | Peter   | Son    |  Male  |  Chennai       | Student
 13  | Johny   | Depp   |  Male  |  Coimbatore    | Student
```

Table 2 (Skills):

```
 S.No| ID | Keyskill  
 ___________________________________________________
 70  | 13 | PHP
 71  | 13 | Whatever Language
 72  | 12 | JAVA
```

Table 1 defines the people you want to save skills for and table 2 just references those by the iD field.

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION :

```
select a.`ID` as ID, a.`F.Name` as first_name, a.`L.Name` as last_name, b.`Title` as tittle, a.`Gender` as gender, a.`Parentaddress` as parent_address, b.keyskill as keyskill from table_1 a inner join table_2 b on a.id = b.`S.No` where b.keyskill LIKE 'php%'
union all
select a.`S.No` as ID, b.`F.Name` as first_name, b.`L.Name` as last_name, a.`Title` as tittle, a.`Gender` as gender, b.`Parentaddress` as parent_address, a.`Keyskill` as keyskill from table_2 a inner join table_1 b where b.parentaddress LIKE 'chennai%'
```

or maybe Join by ID :

```
select * from table_1 a left outer join table_2 b on a.id = b.`S.No` where b.keyskill LIKE 'php%' and a.parentaddress LIKE 'chennai%'
```

Comment: No  i am using keyskill and parent address are search values but these two fields are different tables if keyskil as php it returns corresponding value at the same if i choose parent address as chennai it returns corresponding value.

Comment: at the same if i use keyskill as php and parent address as coimbotore it return corressponcing value at the same

Comment: There is nothing special about it, you just need add the condition. Just get the concept first. Read my updated answer.